# How do I send a form but stay on the same page with phalcon?

Tags: php, forms, controller, handler, phalcon

In the form I have to define a handler like `admin/login`. Then it changes the page when I send it. I also tried using `public function indexAction()` handler and only using the controller `admin` without a handler, but then nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
I wanted to have a error message but it was not so big a site that i wanted to make a form class.

The way i eventually fixed it was the following:

First i use `$this->view->pick('admin/index');` in the handler to select my old view. 
Next i send a variable like a error message with `$this->view->setVars(['username' => $user->name,]);` in the handler.
Last i used it with volt in the previous view `views/admin/index.phtml` like this `{{ username }}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a form object you can then use the following code in your volt template

```
{{ form('myform', 'method':'post', 'role': 'form') }}
```

This will post your data to the same controller/action that invoked the form. From then you will be able to handle the posted data using `valid()` in the form as well as `request->isPost()`